# Combining Bacon.Bus values with value from promise

Tags: javascript, promise, frp, bacon.js

I am taking small steps in FRP land with [BaconJS](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js). I have the following code:

```
# This will eventually get resolved with some value
dfd = Promise.defer()
promised = Bacon.fromPromise dfd.promise

# Values are occasionally being pushed in here
bus = new Bacon.Bus

# 1. attempt
bus.combine promised, (fromBus, fromPromise) ->
   # This is never invoked

# 2. attempt
Bacon.combineAsArray( bus, promised ).onValues (fromBus, fromPromise) ->
   # This is invoked only once for the latest value from the bus

# 3. attempt
promised.sampledBy(bus).onValue (fromPromise, fromBus) ->
   # No invoke here at all

# These are called asynchronously during application lifespan
bus.push obj1
dfd.resolve value
bus.push obj2
bus.push obj3
```

I want to update every delivered object through Bus with the value from the promise object including those, that were pushed there before promise was resolved. I could do something this:

```
bus.onValue (fromBus) ->
    promise.then (fromPromise) ->
        ...
```

Yes, that works, but I just don't like it and I want to see if FRP can solve it more elegantly. Do you have any hints how do it pure FRP way, please ?

### Update

I was thinking about some other approaches. Here is some background what's going on actually...

```
# Simple function that creates some object instance (if it haven't been created yet ) and returns it
getObject = (name) ->
   unless obj = list[name]
     obj = new Obj()
     bus.push obj
```

For every object added to the cache I need to set some property to value that comes from the Promise. Basically I could do it like this:

```
obj = new Obj()
dfd.promise.then (resolvedValue) ->
    obj.someProperty = resolvedValue
```

This is perfectly viable solution without FRP, however as you may know, every `.then` call is forced to be asynchronous. It pays it's price with lowered performance. I would like to overcome this. If I understand it correctly, using FRP it would call `.then` just once and then provide static value. Question remains how to do it...

### Solved

Check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k48qH/). In short, it can look like this:

```
bus.flatMap(
    Bacon.combineAsArray.bind Bacon, promised
).onValue ([fromPromise, fromBus]) ->
    fromBus.specialProperty = fromPromise
```

Comment: Nice to see you making progress! Just a side note - a promise is a one time thing that only resolves once, thus a `Bacon.fromPromise` creates a stream that only gets one value, or an error. Why are you using the deferred here?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Deferred is just for sake of example so you can see I am resolving it somewhere in the middle. I thought that using `fromPromise` will watch for promise resolution and than keep to value and provide it for any consumers. Isn't that correct ? Would it help to convert it `.toProperty` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `flatMap` (again):

```
busValuesWithPromise = bus.flatMap (busValue) ->
    Bacon.combineAsArray(promised, busValue)
busValuesWithPromise.onValues (fromPromise, fromBus) ->
    # every bus update, together with the promise value
```

Comment: Well, this looks totally same as my solution without FRP :) Guess that FRP is not that magical. I would rather see some solution with less closure and having both values in one function call as you can seen in my three failed attempts.

Comment: Well, the point is that it does return a stream now - i might not have emphasized this enough.

Comment: Hmm, I see, but that's just sugar. Closures will be still in there :(

Comment: Well, FRP is always "just sugar" :-) However, to sugar the closure away, I've now found what I think is the proper function for this: [`combineAsArray`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#bacon-combineasarray)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi ! This definitely looks somewhat nicer, although I don't like much about that creating new stream and then having to use `onValues`, but I guess that's just part of FRP that I have to accept :) I made small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k48qH/) with working solution and polished it little bit.

Comment: Oh, nice! I thought about shortening it like that, but it seemed a little too complicated - good if you're fine with it. The more explicit snippet looks easier to understand.